# GtkLabel is not wrapping after updating its content

Tags: gtk, gtk3

here is the code i am using :

```
    messageCrypte= gtk_label_new("");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(messageCrypte, 400, 100);
    gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(messageCrypte), TRUE);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(cryptTab), messageCrypte, 0, ++i, 2, 1);
```

when i initialize the label manually by passing a string to the gtk_label_new , the text is wrapped , 
but when updating the GtkLabel , it increment the window size to the infinite without wrapping,

from the docs :

> Note that setting line wrapping to TRUE does not make the label wrap
>   at its parent container’s width, because GTK+ widgets conceptually
>   can’t make their requisition depend on the parent container’s size.
>   For a label that wraps at a specific position, set the label’s width
>   using gtk_widget_set_size_request().

i did what it is said but no results !

Comment: I don't remember for sure, but have you also tried setting the line wrap mode (for instance, to PANGO_WRAP_WORD)?

Comment: A debugging step I might try, instead of editing the element's content, try replacing the elopement entirely; if that wraps correctly, consider comparing the attributes/properties that are different between the content-replaced element and the respawned element. ? Just a guess.

Comment: this is exactly what i want to try !!!! i got the same idea !
the problem is getting the GtkLabel properties !!!! 
i dealing with g_object_get ... but it is heavy to use for all properties of the widget !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in the wrap mode ,
the wrapd mode is '...WORD' by default that's mean it will wrap when :
(the limit is exceeded AND there is a new word)
but i was entering a string example that dont contains space so it will consider it a one word , 
but when setting the wrao mode to '...CHAR' it will wrap when :
(the limit is exceeded AND there is a new char) the 2nd condition is always verified ofcourse ,